# how to shrink number of data in an array in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a dataset that has more than 50,000 records

it looks like this

```
PtsID     VisitID     Diseaes
134       529         [Pancreatitis, Anxiety, Bronchitis]
134       909         [Dementia]
608       335         [Fibroids, Anxiety]
531       180         [Nosebleed, Dementia, Pancreatitis, Stroke]
531       773         [Stroke]
599       552         [Tonsillitis, Fibroids]
926       643         [Flu, Depression, Depression]
505       935         [Kidney stones, Bronchitis]
791       359         [Covid]
...
...
960       089         [Scabies, Norovirus, Kidney stones, Hay fever]
827       228         [Schizophrenia]
827       359         [Depression, Chilblains, Allergies]
664       690         [Thrush, Scabies, Flu]
```

I want to limit this list of diseases by only keeping the top 100 most common diseases

so the list will be like this (assuming these diseases on the top 100 common diseaese

```
Anxiety, Bronchitis, Dementia, Flu, Depression, Schizophrenia, Allergies


PtsID     VisitID     Diseaes
134       529         [Anxiety, Bronchitis]
134       909         [Dementia]
608       335         [Anxiety]
531       180         [Dementia]
531       773         []
599       552         []
926       643         [Flu, Depression]
505       935         [Bronchitis]
791       359         []
...
...
960       089         []
827       228         [Schizophrenia]
827       359         [Depression, Allergies]
664       690         [Flu]
```

and then delete records that has no diseases and keep the ones that have one ore more diseases

```
PtsID     VisitID     Diseaes
134       529         [Anxiety, Bronchitis]
134       909         [Dementia]
608       335         [Anxiety]
531       180         [Dementia]
926       643         [Flu, Depression]
505       935         [Bronchitis]
...
...
827       228         [Schizophrenia]
827       359         [Depression, Allergies]
664       690         [Flu]
```

I have not worked with array in dataframe before and not sure how to start

Comment: just to clarify, are we looking for the top 100 diseases in the dataset, or are we given the top 100 diseases beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
n = 10

# get the frequency of each disease, and then the top n, and then turn it into a list
l = df['Diseases'].explode().value_counts().head(n).index.tolist()

# get the intersection of each 'Diseases' list with our top diseases list
df['Diseases'] = [list(set(x).intersection(l)) for x in df['Diseases']]
```

Comment: Thanks but which part in the code sorts the diseases descending? does value_counts() gets the count and sort desc?
How to remove records with an empty disease list?

Comment: @asmgx if you just run `df['Diseases'].explode().value_counts()` by itself, you'll see it's in descending order :-)

Answer (score 1):

first of all count the frequency of each disease in the dataset and
sort them based on their frequency in descending order, after that select the top `100` most common diseases and iterate through the dataset and keep only the records that have at least one disease from the selected top `100` list, let me show you with an example :

```
import pandas as pd

#replace `'your_dataset.csv'` with the path to your actual dataset file.
data = pd.read_csv('your_dataset.csv')
disease_counts = data['Diseaes'].apply(eval).explode().value_counts()

#selecting the top 100 most common diseases
top_diseases = disease_counts.index[:100]

filtered_data = data[data['Disease'].apply(lambda x: any(disease in eval(x) for disease in top_diseases))]

print(filtered_data)
```

good luck !

Comment: Thanks but which part in the code sorts the diseases descending? does value_counts() gets the count and sort desc?
How to remove records with an empty disease list?

Comment: @asmgx `disease_counts = data['Diseaes'].apply(eval).explode().value_counts()` calculates the count of each disease, and to remove records with an empty disease list `filtered_data = data[data['Disease'].apply(lambda x: bool(eval(x)) and any(disease in eval(x) for disease in top_diseases))]`